# Does list::insert break the iterators in c++?

Tags: c++, list, pointers

If i have:

```
std::list<int> mylist = { 3 };
auto it = mylist.begin();
```

but i start to do a lot of adds:

```
mylist.insert(it, 5); mylist.insert(it, 7);
```

is there any possibility that `it` could be breaked? (for example, by realocation of the `std::list`) what about `push_back`? can this other function make a pointer invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reallocation for `std::list`; [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) won't invalidate any iterators, and same for [`push_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back).

> No iterators or references are invalidated.

Comment: so, if a `std::list` has only 2 spaces internally, how are those iterators never breaked?

Comment: *`std::list` has only 2 spaces internally*, `std::list` doesn't have such concepts, it is usually implemented as a doubly-linked list; it's not `std::vector`.